# Deleting cookies created by google, but visible on my site?

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused as to how this happens:

[image]

They are created using a "Google Login" method. The login method works fine, but the issue I'm having, is that if someone logs in to the wrong account, there is no way for them to switch to another google account. My understanding of cookies, is that only you can create cookies on YOUR domain - not google (or anyone else)... so how do these exist , but with the domain `.google.com` ?

As a test, I've deleted those cookies, and then the next time it works as expected (asking them to select the account they want to log in as)

So, a silly question, but how can I "delete" those cookies? I've tried it with:

```
// Function to delete all cookies on the current domain
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i];
      var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
      var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
      document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/";
    }
  }
```

But that only deleted the cookies where `domain` => mydomains (and not the .google.com ones)

There must be a way we can tell google to log us out, and show the account selection page again on the next login?

Comment: Those cookies are created when you redirect to the login page (google domain), so the only way to delete those is to visit the google domain again for logging out. (Is should provide you a logout method)

Comment: @Eldar thanks , thats what I thought. But even going directly to google.com, logging out, then going back to my site - the next time I log in , it just goes right to the account I was logged in as before (without asking me which account I want to use)

Comment: Going directly is not how you logged in. You logged in with oidc and you should log out with oidc